# PHPWebsocket client instantly disconnects

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I'm playing around with the `phpwebsocket` class found here http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/ , but my client disconnects as soon as the page loads.

I've enabled sockets in my local php WAMP server, and made sure the URLs that are hardcoded into the code are pointing to the correct locations.

I've tried with both Chrome 20 and IE 10.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided that the problems I'm having with this particular example are because the server was written using an old version of the protocol (the last update to the source was in 2010).  For those interested in one that is working currently, check out https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat.